# How to get element with css in PageObject

Tags: watir, page-object-gem

In the project on which I add tests, I have some elements complicated to "get".
The html of my textarea :

```
<div class="quote">        
 <div class="clearfix">          
  <div class="icon"></div>            
   <div class="text">
    <span class="yui3-widget yui3-inputwidget yui3-textareawidget yui3-textareawidget-focused" style="">
     <span class="yui3-textareawidget-content">
      <textarea name="" placeholder=""></textarea>
     </span>
    </span>
   </div>        
   <div class="author">
    (...) other text_field 
   </div>
  </div>        
 </div>    
</div>
```

For the moment, I use this line to set value

```
@browser.element(:css => ".quote textarea").send_keys "test"
```

In PageObject, I should declare the element and use it :

```
# declaration at the top
element(:quote_text, :css => ".quote textarea") 
# use it where I need
self.quote_text = "text"
```

But I get this error when I use :

```
undefined method `quote_text=' for #<PublishPage:0x33843c0> (NoMethodError)
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: When I try 
    self.quote_text_element.send_keys "test"
I got another error :
    (eval):1: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting $end
     {:css=>".quote textarea"}(identifier)
                               ^ (SyntaxError)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `element(:quote_text, :css => ".quote textarea")`, it will only generate the methods (see [doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors#element-instance_method)):

```
quote_text #Returns the text of the element
quote_text_element #Returns the element
quote_text? #Returns if the element exists
```

Since you know it is a text area and want the text area methods, you should declare it as:

```
text_area(:quote_text, :css => ".quote textarea")
```

This will give you the `quote_text=` method you expect (see [doc](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors#text_area-instance_method)).

**Update** - Since Watir-Webdriver only support css-selectors at the element class (see [Issue 124](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/124)), you will also need to change the locator. Two alternative declarations for `quote_text` that seem to work:

```
#Using a block to locate the element:
text_area(:quote_text){ div_element(:class => "quote").text_area_element }

#Using xpath:
text_area(:quote_text, :xpath => '//div[@class="quote"]//textarea')
```

Comment: Another error :  invalid attribute: nil (Watir::Exception::MissingWayOfFindingObjectException) (eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
I will search again, this explanation makes me feel closer to the goal.

Comment: Ah right. This second exception is because Watir-Webdriver does not currently support using the css locator other than the element class [Issue 124](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/issues/124).

Comment: Perfect with the update. I didn't know that it was possible to use a block in the PAgeObject definition. Very useful :)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need `self` there (but I could be wrong).

Try this

```
quote_text = "text"
```

instead of

```
self.quote_text = "text"
```

Comment: I use self "everywhere" in my page-object code.
If i delete self. : it change nothing.
On the quote_text = text, it don't work better
And elsewhere, it works as usual