# Need to fire an event after entering text in a text_field

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a need so as to enter some text in a text field and then tabout of the text field so that the value in the text field gets validated by a service. I tried to click some other elements in the page but that apparently did not trigger an event to call the service. Is there a workaround in this case? Thank you!

```
class MyPage

 include PageObject
 text_field(:txtinput, :id => 'textV1')
 span(:for,:id   =>  'For' )

  def enter_my_info(data)
    self.txtinput = data
    self.for_element.click  # click someother element in the page
  end 
end
```

Comment: also assess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531705/how-to-get-element-with-css-in-pageobject?rq=1 and see if it helps you

Comment: Added code. It does not error but then the trigger does not happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That type of behaviour often is often triggered by an 'onblur' event. You can manually trigger this use the page object element's `fire_event` method.

```
def enter_my_info(data)
  self.txtinput = data
  self.txtinput_element.fire_event('onblur')
end
```

If that does not work, you could try mimicking the user behaviour and input a tab character. You can send special keys via the `send_keys` method.

```
def enter_my_info(data)
  self.txtinput = data
  self.txtinput_element.send_keys(:tab)
end
```

Comment: Thank you Justin. For some reason the send_keys(:tab) did not work out. I then tried self.someotherelemnt.focus and I was able to trigger the event. I was also able to use the fire_event('onblur') as well without any problems!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried sending the tab key on the element

http://watirwebdriver.com/sending-special-keys/

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up just clicking parent:

```
t = b.text_field(class: 'uploadFileTitle', tracknum: index.to_s)
t.set(track.name)
t.parent.click // loses focus here
```